# How to change the encode url with php?

Tags: php, url, decode, encode

I am developing a project where do I need to encode the id that I am passing so that the Id of mine is not shown to the user. So I have developed that but I am getting an error as 'Fatal error: Cannot redeclare encryptString() (previously declared )' this is shown when I am using it with loop but without the loop it is working very fine. I am pasting the codes with a hope that you may find out any errors into it.
Here is my code

```
<div id="cars">
<?php  
$sl_rp = "select * from $tb_products where status='active' order by id DESC";
$res_rp = mysqli_query($conn,$sl_rp);
if($res_rp){
    $nums_rp = mysqli_num_rows($res_rp);
    if($nums_rp > 0){
        $i=0;
        while($rows_rp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_rp)){
            // $productid = $rows_rp['id'].'/'.'asdfghjklqweretyuiophjgbcfhdgvsf';
            // $t_encode = base64_encode($productid);
        $id = $rows_rp['id'];
        function encryptString($plaintext, $password, $encoding = null) {
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, "AES-256-CBC", hash('sha256', $password, true), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext.$iv, hash('sha256', $password, true), true);
        return $encoding == "hex" ? bin2hex($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext) : ($encoding == "base64" ? base64_encode($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext) : $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext);
        }

        function decryptString($ciphertext, $password, $encoding = null) {
            $ciphertext = $encoding == "hex" ? hex2bin($ciphertext) : ($encoding == "base64" ? base64_decode($ciphertext) : $ciphertext);
            if (!hash_equals(hash_hmac('sha256', substr($ciphertext, 48).substr($ciphertext, 0, 16), hash('sha256', $password, true), true), substr($ciphertext, 16, 32))) return null;
            return openssl_decrypt(substr($ciphertext, 48), "AES-256-CBC", hash('sha256', $password, true), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, substr($ciphertext, 0, 16));
        }

        echo $enc = encryptString($id, "myPassword", "hex");
            $i++;
?>
<div class="item">
    <div class="teaser <?php if($i % 3 == 0){ echo "card-3"; }else if($i % 2 == 0){ echo "card-2"; }else{ echo "card-1"; } ?> transp with_padding big-padding margin_0">
        <div class="media xxs-media-left">
            
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <div class="teaser_icon size_small big_wrapper">

                
                    <img src="upload_products/<?php echo $rows_rp['p_upload']; ?>" class="img-responsive img-center mar-top-5"> 
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body media-middle">
                <h4 class="text-white"><?php echo $rows_rp['pname']; ?></h4>
                <a href="fill-details.php?product=<?php echo $enc; ?>" class="btn btn-default text-capitalize card_buttons">Order Now</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
        }
        
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Declare the function outside the loop.

Comment: @ceejayoz okay i am trying to do

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz it worked for me but can I ask you for one more help??? Does this way for encryption will work or is it safe to use.

Comment: I don't know what the code's purpose is, why you want to encrypt this data, etc., so that's difficult to answer.

Comment: I just dont want to show the id value to the user for that

Comment: And also it is not giving any issues while decoding too but does it is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first i would like to say that the suggestion provided by the @ceejayoz is correct and please use the function in your file where like you are using the connection codes below of that then you will not face any issues, this is a safe method but nothing is safe into the internet although you can use it.